# List View of Pipeline views in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins I can create a "List View" and sort all the jobs you want in that list. Can a similar list view be created where I can sort out all my "Build pipeline Views" based on different catagories?

My pipelines:

```
pipeline1 : Job A -> Job B -> Job C
pipeline2: Job D -> Job E -> Job F
pipeline3: Job G -> Job H -> Job I
pipeline4: Job J -> Job K -> Job L
```

My list view should list the pipeline like so:

```
ListView1: pipeline1, pipeline3
ListView2: pipeline2, pipeline4
```

Is there any plugin which can help me with this or any other alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

1. You can use [Jenkins Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) which will be a best fit for your scenario.
2. You can sort these by **only configuring in Jenkins** based on the order which you have asked in the question, as Jenkins thread will execute based on your Job configuration in Admin UI Screen.